# Android: How do you observe the view's layout constraints when drawing with a canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I work on an android application but I have trouble oberserving my custom view's layout constraints when drawing with a canvas on my custom view.

[image]

That's my custom view's class:

```
public class GraphView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;

    public GraphView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

   /**
   * Returns the view's real x coordinate. Not working :/
   * @return the view's real x coordinate
   */
    public float absX(){
        return getLeft();
    }

    /**
    * Returns the view's real y coordinate. Not working :/
    * @return the view's real y coordinate
    */
    public float absY(){
       return getTop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        setPath(new Path());
        getPath().moveTo(absX(), absY());
        getPath().lineTo(absX()+100, absY()+100);

        setPaint(new Paint());
        getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
        getPaint().setStrokeWidth(5);

        canvas.drawPath(getPath(), getPaint());
    }

    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }

    private void setPaint(Paint paint) {
         this.paint = paint;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    private void setPath(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to get my custom view's real xy-coordinates. *If `absX()` and `absY()` will work my problem is solved.* But these methods return `0`. By doing that they seem to 'ignore' the layout constraints. So when I start the app, the line that I draw using the canvas is placed in the upper left corner of my smartphone. This is wrong, it should be drawn to the upper left corner of my custom view!

[image]

I've already tried to use `(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams()`, `getX()`, `getY()` and `getLocationOnScreen()` but nothing was working correctly.
Could someone *please* help me?

Comment: For the `Canvas` passed into `onDraw()`, the coordinates (0, 0) is the top-left of your `View`. A `View` drawing itself is not (normally) concerned with where it is in its parent. If that custom `View` is drawing in an unexpected location, then it would seem that the `View` itself is not where you think it is.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You saved me a lot of time. The problem was the view's layout width and height. They were set to `fill_parent` which caused an unwanted position.